# Android Screenshot in PHP

Tags: php, android, adb, android-sdk-2.3

Is it possible to take a screenshot of my Android device using PHP?

I suppose that I need to take a screenshot using `adb` (`exec an adb command`) and then display the result in my PHP code?

Have someone tried something similar?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why? I cannot imagine anything bad with that!

Comment: But you can only access devices connected to the server. Not the actual client's device

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way you can do that is running PHP code in your Android device and running an external program, thats because PHP can't see/"touch" the client side when you are browsing a website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible when the device is connected to the system running PHP and the user running PHP has access rights to USB.

You need the following software for my quick & dirty solution: `BASH` (or similar), `ffmpeg`, `adb` and `PHP` with `shell_exec`.

**screenshot.sh**

```
adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 && \
ffmpeg -vframes 1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 480x854 -i fb0 screenshot.png
```

It is important to adjust the screen resolution (480x854).

**Test**

```
php -r 'echo shell_exec("sh ./screenshot.sh");'
```

Thanks to http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1405275